# persistant TCP connection in Django

Tags: python, django, tcp, twisted

I have a Django application which sometimes needs to send some data through TCP and I want this connection to be persistant.

The way I wanted to do it was to create a simple Twisted TCP server (I'm the one who will be waiting for the initial connection) and somehow call it from a Django view whenever I would be needing it.

How should the communication look like beetwen Twisted and Django in this case?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you're asking. Do you want the connection between Django and your Twisted server to be persistent? If so, why? Performance?

Comment: Yes, performance. If not then probably I would drop TCP connection in favour of some AMQP solution for django like Carrot. In this case I need to send a very small message to a remote server from time to time. I was also wondering if I could do that directly from a users brower using Orbit but I have no clue if it might work.

Comment: one example implementation fo a stomp server with orbited and django is: http://github.com/clemesha/hotdot .  Is that close to what you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand how Hotdot works. As I see it uses Twisted to serve Orbit, right? And as I said - I don't know how exactly I could use Orbit in my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [Twisted wsgi container to run Django](http://blog.dreid.org/2009/03/twisted-django-it-wont-burn-down-your.html).  This container simply runs the WSGI application in multiple Twisted-threadpool threads, so you can simply call any Twisted API via [`blockingCallFromThread`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/10.1.0/api/twisted.internet.threads.html).  There's really not that much to it!

Comment: Although I didn't take this approach (a similar one though) I think that this should work as well. 

Anyway, Your answer led me to the solution, so thanks!

Comment: @virtuallight Which solution did you use?